# Swap function returning array

Tags: c

Trying to understand how a pointer works in a function that returns an array.

When the temp array is returned to the function, why is it that p[0] is 1 and p[1] is 3? Since x and y variable are swapped within the function and temp[0] and temp[1] are not swapped.

```
int *swap(int *x, int *y){
  static int temp[2];

  temp[0] = *x; 
  temp[1] = *y;
  *x = temp[1];
  *y = temp[0];
  return temp;
}


int main() {

  int x = 3;
  int y = 1;
  int *p = swap(&x, &y);
    GPIO_PORTF_AHB_DATA_BITS_R[LED_RED] = LED_RED;//turn on red led
    delay(p[0]);

    GPIO_PORTF_AHB_DATA_BITS_R[LED_RED] = 0;//turn off red led
    delay(p[1]);

  }
```

Comment: *When the temp array is returned to the function* – You are not returning an array. A pointer is not an array and an array is not a pointer. Besides: Naming a `static` variable "`temp`" is highly misleading. Your `temp` exists from program startup until `main()` returns and there is only ever one.

Comment: Why do you use `int main()` on a MCU program? Why did you remove the loop? Where do you expect to return to after executing?

Comment: Was following a youtube video to learn TIVA C programming. Removed the loop so it would unclutter my queries. As mentioned, the swap function is used to swap values for delay() to achieve a sequence of ON,OFF state on the LED.

Answer (score 3):

> why is it that p[0] is 1 and p[1] is 3

It isn't.

Replacing your microcontroller-specific code with:

```
printf("p[0] = %d, p[1] = %d\n", p[0], p[1]);
```

and running your code on a computer gives me the output:

```
p[0] = 3, p[1] = 1
```

as expected.

Comment: I have excluded the "While" loop in my MCU code. The idea was to achieve a 3 sec "ON", 1sec "OFF" on the LED and then 1sec "ON" with 3sec "OFF" reversal. Thanks for pointing out, the reversal will occur with alternate loop.